# Diverging arrows, tikz/pgf - flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-arrows

I've spent hours trying to draw the picture below in tikz. I can't figure out how to draw the diverging arrows, would be very grateful for any advices on the matter!

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please post the code you've spent hours writing so that somebody can help you with the arrows without needing to start the whole thing from scratch. A complete, compilable example would be best.

Comment: I would just use a `\coordinate` to create a coordinate at the relevant point, probably, so that I could draw an arrow to it and then two arrows from it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I'm sorry, my code was just a mess and I wrote this post as a last resort. Thank you for your comments, I now realise how bad it looks. Will do better next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considered suggestions in above comments I draw using TikZ (for exercise) the following graph:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,quotes}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 22mm and 66mm,
    MN/.style = {draw, text width=22mm, minimum height=16mm,
                 align=flush center},
 arrow/.style = {-{Triangle[]},thick}
                    ]
\node (n1) [MN] {Protection seller (investor)};
\node (n2) [MN,right=of n1] {Protection buyer};
\node (n3) [MN,below=of n2] {Reference borrower};
%
%\draw[arrow] ([yshift=4mm] n1.east) to ["Premium"] ([yshift=4mm] n2.west);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=4mm] n2.west) to ["Premium" '] ([yshift=4mm] n1.east);
\path   ([yshift=-4mm] n1.east) -- coordinate (a1)
        ([yshift=-4mm] n2.west)    coordinate (a2);
\draw[arrow] (n1.east |- a1) to ["No credit event","Credit event" '] (a1); 
\draw[arrow] (a1) |- node[pos=0.75,above] {No payment}   ([yshift=+2mm] a2); 
\draw[arrow] (a1) |- node[pos=0.75,below] {Payment}      ([yshift=-2mm] a2);
%
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-6mm] n2.south) edge node[below,sloped] {Repayment}
                                                     ([xshift=-6mm] n3.north)
              (n3) edge node[below,sloped] {Interest} (n2)
             ([xshift=+6mm] n3.north)  to  node[below,sloped] {Repayment}
                                                     ([xshift=+6mm] n2.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** in code is changed arrow orientation ...

Comment: Protection buyer must pay premium to protection seller so that on default protection seller will pay the loss to protection buyer. so the top arrow should be towards protection seller and not as shown above

Comment: Well, I do most of your work (and made service do-it-for-me ... what is not intention of SE). In it I didn't bother with arrows orientation, actually I left this to you.